# Rails 5.1+ routing: `resources` not working but explicit route definition does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

**Update**

This was a legacy app I inherited, and I found out that the previous developers had removed the rack code that converted browser POST requests into PUT/PATCH based on the `_method` param that Rails adds to your forms.

```
# config/application.rb
# This is the line that caused the problem...
config.middleware.delete ::Rack::MethodOverride
```

Once I removed that line and restarted the server, things worked as expected.

**Original Question**

When I post a Rails form using the standard `resources` in the routes file, it raises a `route not found` error when I'm trying to update an existing record:

`No route matches [POST] "/admin/lookups/record_types/1"`

The model is namespaced as `app/models/lookups/record_type.rb`

```
# model file
module Lookups
  class RecordType < ApplicationRecord
    # ...
  end
end

# form in view file
<%= form_with model: @record_type, scope: :record_type, url: [:admin, @record_type], local: true do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :value %>
<% end %>

# Request being sent
POST admin/lookups/record_types/1
{ record_type: { _method: "patch", value: "value" } }

# in routes .rb
namespace :admin do
  namespace :lookups do
    # Does not work
    resources :record_types

    # Works when explicitly written out
    post "record_types/:id", controller: record_types, action: :update
  end
end
```

When I explicitly write out the POST request in the `routes.rb` file, it works as expected.

I know that Rails is actually `POSTing` the request and using the `_method` hidden attribute to map the routes file.  However, something isn't converting that request properly.

It's an application I inherited, and at one point it was exclusively an JSON API (no direct UI), so I'm wondering if there was something removed that converted the Rails `_method` param to the proper controller?  I don't know what that would be, though.

This is the output of my `rake routes`:

```
admin_lookups_record_types
GET /admin/lookups/record_types(.:format)   
  admin/lookups/record_types#index
POST /admin/lookups/record_types(.:format) 
    admin/lookups/record_types#create

new_admin_lookups_record_type
GET /admin/lookups/record_types/new(.:format)
    admin/lookups/record_types#new

edit_admin_lookups_record_type
GET /admin/lookups/record_types/:id/edit(.:format) 
    admin/lookups/record_types#edit

admin_lookups_record_type
GET /admin/lookups/record_types/:id(.:format) 
    admin/lookups/record_types#show
PATCH /admin/lookups/record_types/:id(.:format) 
    admin/lookups/record_types#update
PUT /admin/lookups/record_types/:id(.:format)
    admin/lookups/record_types#update
DELETE /admin/lookups/record_types/:id(.:format)
    admin/lookups/record_types#destroy
```

Comment: Post what routes are printed when you type "rails routes" on the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the use of the `scope` argument to the `form_with` method.
If you take a look at the routes you'll note that the route to the `update` action uses `PUT` or `PATCH` whereas the route to the `create` action uses `POST`.

As the documentation of the [FormHelper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) module states:

> in the options hash. If the verb is not GET or POST, which are natively supported by HTML forms, the form will be set to POST and a hidden input called _method will carry the intended verb for the server to interpret.

But nesting the special `_method` key inside `record_type` breaks this mechanism. Is the scope really necessary? I'd try removing it, it should work fine without it. The correct HTTP verb to use would be `PUT` or `PATCH`. Adding an additional `POST` route breaks the regular Rails structure without any real gain.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The `scope` argument shouldn't affect the `_method` param because Rails adds that in itself using the `form_with` builder.  I verified that by viewing the HTML form generated using devtools on the browser.  If I don't use the `scope` argument, then the form builder will try and nest the attributes under `lookups[:record_type][:value]`, and I just want the `record_type[:value]` arguments instead.

Comment: Did you check that? I just took a look at the [source for `Rack::MethodOverride`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/method_override.rb) and it only checks the top-level params, without going into a nested hash.